# Are protected constructors considered good practice?

Tags: php, oop

I'm writing some little helper classes to handle trees. Basically, I have a node and a special root node that represents the tree. I want to keep it generic and simple. This is part of the code:

```
<?php

class Tree extends TreeNode{
    public function addById($node_id, $parent_id, $generic_content){
        if( $parent = $this->findNodeById($parent_id) ){
            $parent->addChildById($node_id, $generic_content);
        }
    }
}

class TreeNode{
    public function __construct($node_id, $parent_id, $generic_content){
        // ...
    }

    protected function addChildById($node_id, $generic_content){
        $this->children[] = new TreeNode($this->node_id, $node_id, $generic_content);
    }
}

$Categories = new Tree;
$Categories->addById(1, NULL, $foo);
$Categories->addById(2, NULL, $bar);
$Categories->addById(3, 1, $gee);

?>
```

My questions:

- Is it sensible to force `TreeNode` instances to be created through `TreeNode::addById()`?
- If it's so, would it be good practise to declare `TreeNode::__construct()` as private/protected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that in certain cases it does make sense to control the construction of objects and hide the public constructor.

This is true of your code: it's useful for the `Tree` class to control how it's child `TreeNode`s are created and initialized because it needs to control where nodes are added in the tree hierarchy.

Having this control over object construction is especially important if the relationship between the classes is such that the one has information about the other.

For example: if you changed your implementation slightly and allowed the `Tree` class to manage the node IDs for all nodes in the tree (you might store these in an array within the `Tree` class). In this case it would be very compelling to have `Tree` control how `TreeNode`s are created and initialized and doing this through a method on your `Tree` class makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

> - Is it sensible to force `TreeNode` instances to be created through `TreeNode::addById()`?
> - If it's so, would it be good practise to declare `TreeNode::__construct()` as private/protected?

If you want to force `TreeNode` to be created through `TreeNode::addById()`, the **only** sensible path is to make the `TreeNode::__construct()` private or protected (both would work in this case, but `private` would  probably be better since it would force the subclasses to use `::addChildById`).

As to whether it's sensible to force `TreeNode` instances to be created through `TreeNode::addById()`: it is, the alternative would be to transfer `TreeNode::addById()`'s logic to the constructor. While possible in this case, factory methods are generally more versatile.

Note, however, <del>that as it is now</del>, and since calling the parent constructors is not required in PHP, <del>you **can** create (a subtype of) `TreeNode` objects by creating `Tree` objects. You should consider adding a  private constructor to `Tree` to avoid instantiation.</del>

Correction: although it's true that calling the parent constructors is not required in PHP, it's also true that there's an implicit call to the parent constructor if no constructor is specified in the subclass; so as it is right now, PHP would try to call `TreeNode`'s parent constructor and fail when directly instantiation a `Tree` object.